# auto copy newest folders and images in MyPictures folder to USB drive

Tags: windows, usb, images

I drop lots of photos in a day into the My Documents/My Pictures folder.

I archive at the end of each day to USB drives, to be stored offsite. What I would like is someway to automate the process. By example, a small app or script I can simply double-click and it will scan the My Pictures folder for the newest folders and images and copy them to the USB drive until the drive is full.

It doesn't matter if I get redundancy from the previous days saved images, so long as the newest images and folders are always the first to get copied.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try an xcopy command with 'update' option, in a batch file, something like:

```
xcopy C:\Users\username\Pictures D:\Pictures /S/D
```

- /S copy subfolders too
- /D copy newer files only (for some reason this switch does not work properly all the time and it might still copy files that already exist)
- watch for the USB letter drive, it may change ...

I hope this helps you.